# Does invoking javax.persistence.TypedQuery.getResultList cause a transaction to be committed?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, entitymanager

In a Java 1.8 SE environment using Hibernate 5 as my JPA provider, I have the following code:

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EmployeeService");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Employee employee = new Employee(1);
    employee.setName("Bob");
    employee.setSalary(100000);
    
    em.persist(employee);
    
    System.out.println("em" + em.find(Employee.class, 1));          
    System.out.println("em all Employees" + em.createQuery("SELECT e from Employee e", Employee.class).getResultList());
    
    em.clear();
    
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    System.out.println("em after commit " + em.find(Employee.class, 1));            
    System.out.println("em after commit all Employees" + em.createQuery("SELECT e from Employee e", Employee.class).getResultList());

    em.close();
    emf.close();
```

I was expecting this output because of calling `em.clear()` before the commit:

```
emEmployee(id=1, name=Bob, salary=100000.0)
em after commit null
em after commit all Employees[]
```

but got:

```
emEmployee(id=1, name=Bob, salary=100000.0)
em all Employees[Employee(id=1, name=Bob, salary=100000.0)]
em after commit Employee(id=1, name=Bob, salary=100000.0)
em after commit all Employees[Employee(id=1, name=Bob, salary=100000.0)]
```

If I comment out the line with the `getResultList()` call just before `em.clear()`, I get the expected output. Why don't I get the output I expected when calling `getResultList`?

Comment: You can see for yourself by turning on SQL logging - it would show inserts/updates before it executes the query. It is up to the provider how to handle it, and can be configured with flushMode settings which you haven't shown and could be being used at the persistence unit level: https://thorben-janssen.com/flushmode-in-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @Chris - Thanks for your comment. That is very helpful and now I understand the results in my OP. I didn't set a flush mode so it defaults to AUTO. After reading the article and turning on logging, I understand and can see that the query causes the "Bob" employee to be flushed to the database. If you would like, you may post an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL logging will show inserts/updates before it executes the query. It is up to the provider how to handle when to flush statements to the database, but this can be configured by specifying the FlushModeType on the [Query](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setFlushMode-javax.persistence.FlushModeType-), on the [EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#setFlushMode-javax.persistence.FlushModeType-) or the persistence unit with provider specific properties (see [hibernate](https://thorben-janssen.com/flushmode-in-jpa-and-hibernate/) and [EclipseLink](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_persistence_context_flushmode.htm))